# Regex - parsing string into groups

Tags: java, regex

I have specific log messages and I would like to parse it into groups. I would like to make an alternative version in case if my string is more specific.

My logs:

```
18:48:24:284 => [DEBUG] [xxx.yyy.zzz] [8] Message1
18:48:24:671 => [INFO] [uuu.www.aaa] [8] Method: 'ReturnType MethodName(MethodParameter)'. Line: ~30. Message2
```

I have written the following regex:

```
(?<timestamp>\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+.*)\s+=>\s+\[(?<level>\w+)\]\s+\[(?<emmiter>.*)\]\s+\[(?<thread>\d+)\]\s+(?<message>.*)
```

It parses these messages into specific groups:

```
timestamp: 18:48:24:284
level: DEBUG
emmiter: xxx.yyy.zzz
thread: 8
message: Message1

timestamp: 18:48:24:671
level: INFO
emmiter: uuu.www.aaa
thread: 8
message: Method: 'ReturnType MethodName(MethodParameter)'. Line: ~30. Message2
```

But right now I would like to add 2 more groups, in case if they exist: method and Line

So, I would like to get results like this:

```
timestamp: 18:48:24:284
level: DEBUG
emmiter: xxx.yyy.zzz
thread: 8
method:
line: 
message: Message1

timestamp: 18:48:24:671
level: INFO
emmiter: uuu.www.aaa
thread: 8
method: ReturnType MethodName(MethodParameter)
line: ~30
message: Message2
```

Can you please help me with that? Everything I do results in parsing only `Line1` or only `Line2` properly, but I would like to parse them both with one regex.

Comment: Which lang are you running? Where is your attempts?

Comment: Which development environment / language are you using ? Please add appropriate tags to your question! Also, please provide the regex expression you have already written!

Comment: I'm using it in external application.  I assume it's java.
I have updated post with my current state of regex

Comment: OK! What application is that?

Comment: @SQLPolice I'm writing regex  parser for LogMX application

Comment: Ah, OK! LogMX = Log File Analyzer. Link: http://www.logmx.com

Comment: BTW. I have added group names to readability. Basically groups should be without names to be parsed correctly by LogMX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest the following regular expression:

```
(?<timestamp>\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+.*)\s+=>\s+\[(?<level>\w+)\]\s+\[(?<emmiter>.*)\]\s+\[(?<thread>\d+)\](?:\s+Method:\s'(?<method>[^']*)'\s*\.)?(?:\s*Line:\s*(?<line>.+)\.)?\s*(?<message>.*)
                                                                                                                     ^^^^^^              ^                  ^^^^       ^
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cU8nT0/1)

I added 2 optional groups with non-capturing groups and a `?` quantifier `(?:...)?` called `method`and `line`.

I suggest using `(?<method>[^']*)` to capture all symbols other than `'` to capture method name, and `Line:\s*(?<line>.+)\.` to capture `line` that is too greedy because I am not sure what text you might have there. You can actually adjust the `(?<line>.+)` part to some more restrictive pattern (I thought of `~?\d+` but no idea if you may have colons or anything else there).

Comment: Please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications in case you have any doubts about this. I posted some considerations above in the answer.